# Build and Publish (ASP.NET Web Application) using c# in Button_Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

I want to publish the asp.net(web Application), when i click the button(Button_Click) Event.

As per below MSBuild script successfully published using VS2008 comment prompt at Run as administrator.

*Note:*
msbuild D:\Test.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutDir= D:\Test_Publish_Folder\

how to call the above msbuild command using c# in Button_Click event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
Make sure that you point to the correct version of msbuild (depends on the framework and platform your application targets).

It will look something like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe", @"D:\Test.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutDir= D:\Test_Publish_Folder\");
```